# Why do I get undefined from the Promise? - Updated

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to resolve an array with objects, but the array only returns with one value. scrapeModule is returning an array of text-values. Here is the code:

```
"use strict";

var scrapeModule = require("./scrape");

const accounts = function(promiseObj, link) {

    // Update the url-value in promiseObj
    promiseObj.url = promiseObj.url.replace(config.url.substring(19), JSON.parse(link));

    return scrapeModel(promiseObj).then((arrayContainingText) => {
    let arrayIWantToSend = []

            arrayContainingText.forEach(function(nameHTML) {

                    fetchObj(promiseObj, name).then(function(data) {
                    arrayIWantToSend.push(data)

                    return data;
                    console.log(data) =>     
[ { key1: 'v1', key2: 'v2', key3: 'v3'},
  { key1: 'v1', key2: 'v2', key3: 'v3'},
  { key1: 'v1', key2: 'v2', key3: 'v3'} ]

                })
        });
};

const fetchObj = function(promiseObj, link) {

    let keyValues = {};

    // Clone the old promiseObj
    let thObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(promiseObj));
    let tdObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(promiseObj));

    // Replace the track-values
    thObj.track = "th";
    tdObj.track = "td";

    return Promise.all([scrapeModule((thObj)), scrapeModule((tdObj))]).then(data => {
        let key = data[0];
        let v = data[1];

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (let y = 0; y < data[i].length; y++) {

                keyValues[key[y]] = data[y];
            }
        }

           return keyValues
    });

};

module.exports = accounts;
```

I'm logging the result from the promise with this code in another module. I want the returned value from the function to be the array with values:

```
accounts(url, link)
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }); -- > //[ undefined ]
```

But when I console.log "data" in the Promise in accounts(), the array returns:

```
[ { key1: 'v1', key2: 'v2', key3: 'v3'},
  { key1: 'v1', key2: 'v2', key3: 'v3'},
  { key1: 'v1', key2: 'v2', key3: 'v3'} ]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: And what does `scrapeModule` return?

Comment: Where are you logging the value in `accounts()`? Where are you calling `resolve()` for that first promise you are creating? It seems like there's code you're not showing us.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like you're already working with promises, and you're creating entirely too many `new Promises` when you could simply return the ones you already get.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I remade the original code in the question to make it easier to read. I first did a Promise.all with the scrapeModule, and simply setted "data" to be the first variable the promise returned. As for the data, it returns an array with text from an html-document. Thank you for the simplification. I've updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple iteration-problem. The loop didn't work with Promises, so I made an array with multiple promises and sent them in to Promise.all

```
    return scrapeModel(promiseObj).then((arrayContainingText) => {
            var promises = [];

            data.forEach(function(name) {
                promises.push(fetchObj(promiseObj, name))
            });

            return Promise.all(promises).then(function(data) {

                return data;
            }).catch(function(e) {console.log(e)});
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be greatly simplified, considering your use of `let`, then I've also added other ES6 "features" too

```
var scrapeModule = require("./scrape");
const accounts = function(promiseObj, link) {
    // Update the url-value in promiseObj
    promiseObj.url = promiseObj.url.replace(config.url.substring(19), JSON.parse(link));

    return scrapeModel(promiseObj)
    .then(arrayContainingText => 
        Promise.all(arrayContainingText.map(nameHTML => 
            fetchObj(promiseObj, name)
        ))
    );
};

const fetchObj = ... // no changes

module.exports = accounts;
```

I've made no changes to `fetchObj` because now that function looks odd in that it takes an argument `link` that it never uses, and the nested for looks wrong too - suspect it should have `keyValues[key[y]] = data[i][y];` - but you know better because you can run the code and debug it

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I remade the code in the question to make it easier to read. I first did a Promise.all with the scrapeModule, and simply setted "data" to be the first variable the promise returned. As for the data, it returns an array with text from an html-document. Thank you for the simplification, I will try to shorten it

Comment: Tried simplifying it like you showed, thank you. Although, the promise returns undefined now instead. Updated the code in the question